# the .removeChild(child) seems to stop my script from running

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="input">
<input type="text" id="name")"></input>
</div>

<button type="button" id="b1" onclick="changed('click',getElementById('name').value)" value="Log In">Log In</button>

<script>

function changed(action,val)
{
    var op
    var element = document.getElementById("input")
    var child = document.getElementById("name")
    if(action == "click")
    {
        e = document.getElementById("b1")
        if(e.value == "Log In")
        {
            //element.removeChild(child)
            op = "Log Out"
        }
        else if(e.value == "Log Out")
        {
            element.appendChild(child)
            op = "Log In"
        }
        e.value = op
        e.innerHTML = op
    }
}
</script>
```

this is my code and with the line "element.removeChild(child)" commented out the button can be clicked multiple times and the value and text on the button changes as expected. As soon as the comment is removed, button is clickable only once and once the input line is removed nothing functions anymore. I have never worked with this code element before and I am unclear as to why it isn't working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is with the attribute with the name element?

Comment: Once you remove the `<input>`, `getElementById("name")` returns null and null has no attribute `value`...

Comment: but that doesn't explain why it stops the whole process, the element goes away but the button still does nothing from that point on. even when I comment out the appendChild(child) tag the button does nothing.

Comment: For me, when both those lines are commented out, the button still toggles its text.

Comment: @squint for me too, but once the element is removed, the script is useless, and without the input box you can't put in any name for the login.

Comment: So then the second comment from the top explains the issue. You can't fetch properties from `null`, which causes an error, halting the function. You can check for `null` using an `if` statement.

Comment: Still not clear with problem! Do you want to remove the input when button text is log out?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, objective or end result of you script is not clear to me. What I understand is that you have a button with text "Log Out". Once you click on this you will show  a input box and button "Log In" , and again if again it is clicked it will go back to "Log Out". If this is your criteria, then this below snippet may be useful

JS

```
function changed(elem,btn)
{
   var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    if(btn.value == 1){
     element.classList.remove('hide');
      element.classList.add('show');
       btn.value=2;  // Setting button value to 2 
      btn.textContent="Log In";
    }
    else if(btn.value ==2){
      element.classList.remove('show');
      element.classList.add('hide');
       btn.value=1;  // Setting button value to  
      btn.textContent="Log Out";

    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="input" class="hide">
<input type="text" id="name">
</div>

<button type="button" id="b1" onclick="changed('input',this)" value="1">Log Out</button>
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/61ry4s1j/9/).Let me know if it is helpful to you & also if any change is expected.